# Derby.js Front end and Backend interaction

Tags: node.js, derbyjs, node.js-client

I'm new to NodeJs and i'm a core java developer. Can anyone explain me how DerbyJs interacts with Backend and how backend replies to frontend in turn?
I can see many functions. not sure which function i should use for which scene!!

I created a HTML
index.html

```
<Body:>
  <!-- в шаблоне прописывается как html, так и привязки к данным -->
  Holler: <input value="{{hello.message}}">

{{hello1.message}}
 {{hello.message}}
```

corresponding index.JS

```
var app = module.exports = require('derby').createApp('hello', __filename);
app.loadViews(__dirname);

// Маршрут рендерится на клиене и на сервере
app.get('/', function(page, model) {
  // Подписка обеспечивает синхронизацию данных
  model.subscribe('hello.message', function() {

    model.set ( 'hello1.message' , 'text in model' );
     page.render();
    console.log('hello.message');
  });
});
```

my Questions.
1. why should i use hello.message, i tried using simple message in HTML, its not working.
2. I want the front end to displat the static message hello1.message from backend, meanwhile it needs to render the page as i type the in the textbox whose corresponding value s hello.message.

3. how will i handle the Onclick method in derby.js

Answer (score 0):

1. MongoDB requires a collection name, then where something is stored in the collection. Think about it like a table name and a column name. You can't store "message" in sql, you need a table "messages" and then a column to store the value in. (If you are unfamiliar with sql I can try a different analogy)
2. I don't know what your question is, but I think derbyjs re-renders either data or the whole page, is that your question? DerbyJs should just re-render the changed data.
3. If you have a button for example:

   ```
   <button on-click="callFunctionOnServer()">Call Server</button>
   ```